# Fixing merge conflicts with git flow

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-flow, merge-conflict-resolution

I'm using the following flow: There's master, test and feature branches. Feature branches are branched from master. Pull requests are made from feature branches to test and then (when approved) from the feature branch to master. Whenever I make pull request from feature to test, there's a chance a merge conflict occurs. I would like to fix this conflict locally..

My way of doing this is merging the test branch to my feature branch (locally), fix the conflict, and push the merge. Then the pull request is fixed. HOWEVER, this causes **ALL changes (features) from the test branch to come along when I create a PR from that feature branch to master**. This is of course not what I want, since some of those features haven't been tested yet.

What is the best way to fix merge conflicts (locally) without merging the test branch to my feature branch (causing this issue)?

Answer (score 0):

One course of action could be to merge your changes the other way, I mean merging your feature branch into your local copy of the test branch to resolve the conflicts, then push the updated test branch to remote. Feature branch isn't affected and can be merged to master without bringing back all of test branch's unwanted stuff.

However, it's probably a good bet to try a PR from feature to test beforehand, and be happy with it if no conflict arises.

Comment: But if I resolve the conflicts in the local test branch, then the feature branch is not updated with the resolved fixes. The same conflicts will arise when I then make a PR from feature to master.